# difference between format strings

Tags: c#

I've got this code here which formats a decimal with ToString("###0").
But I don't see any differene with just calling ToString()

```
decimal count = 123456;

Console.WriteLine(count.ToString("###0")); // SAME
Console.WriteLine(count.ToString()); // SAME
```

What does ###0 do?

Comment: try "## ###" as a format, and you will see.

Comment: Did you do a quick search before posting and found nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.
>
> Note that no digit appears in the result string if the corresponding digit in the input string is a non-significant 0. For example, 0003 ("####") -> 3.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

So in your case you have a six digit number but only three "#" symbols so it's going to have no effect whatsoever.

If you had more "#"'s or a smaller number, you'd see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you have the official document about custom formats.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

`ToString()` uses a default format, and you can then use any other format you prefer. It just happened that you chose a custom format that in your case matches the default one.

`#` represents a digit, but it's only displayed if it's significant. `0` is any digit but it's always displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation about the custom string formats.

Here is one example, hope it will help...

```
string yourString = digit.ToString("+#;-#");
```

Where each section separated by a semicolon represents positive and negative numbers

or:

```
string yourString = digit.ToString("+#;-#;0");
```

if you don't want the zero to have a plus sign.

Comment: I think that example is overcomplicated for what Servé is asking.

Comment: Yes it is, but well, I said it might help. Better to give full than partial example. @Andrew

Comment: What I meant is that if he can't understand the basics, that example with three syntaxes without explaining what `#` and `0` do won't help much.

Comment: Yes, true, but I think the harder way is better. ;) @Andrew